How to get superscripts in R table1 package units() or label() attributes?
I'm working on making a table using the table1 package in R. One of my variables is measured in mm^3. I'm not able to get a superscript using the table1() function when I assign the unit for this variable as units(df$volume) <- expression("mm"^"3"). The table outputs without the superscript and pastes the argument within the expression() function. Is there a way to show this as a superscript? Thanks


I'm not sure this is the best solution, but maybe something like this could work?
units(df$volume) <- "mmᶾ"


Or, alternatively,
units(df$volume) <- "mmᶟ"


These special characters are taken from https://graphemica.com/%E1%B6%BE and https://graphemica.com/%E1%B5%8C
